# setPasswordAttribute interfering with password reset (Laravel 5.2)

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5

I have been working on the password reset functionality and it works almost entirely, except when I enter the new password login is rejected.

I believe that my setPasswordAttribute() function in the User.php file is interfering with the password reset, as when I comment it out, the reset works fine. I'm not sure exactly how I'm supposed to modify this function in order to make the reset works.

Here is my setPasswordAttribute() function

```
 public function setPasswordAttribute($value)
{
    $this->attributes['password'] = bcrypt($value);
}
```

Here is my password reset code. I simply followed the laravel documentation.

Routes.

```
Route::get('password/email', 'Auth\PasswordController@getEmail');
Route::post('password/email', 'Auth\PasswordController@postEmail');
Route::get('password/reset/{token}', 'Auth\PasswordController@getReset');
Route::post('password/reset', 'Auth\PasswordController@postReset');
```

Email view

```
    <form method="POST" action="/password/email">
    {!! csrf_field() !!}

    @if (count($errors) > 0)
        <ul>
            @foreach ($errors->all() as $error)
                <li>{{ $error }}</li>
            @endforeach
        </ul>
    @endif

    <div>
        Email
        <input type="email" name="email" value="{{ old('email') }}">
    </div>

    <div>
        <button type="submit">
            Send Password Reset Link
        </button>
    </div>
</form>
```

Reset view

```
<form method="POST" action="/password/reset">
{!! csrf_field() !!}
<input type="hidden" name="token" value="{{ $token }}">

@if (count($errors) > 0)
    <ul>
        @foreach ($errors->all() as $error)
            <li>{{ $error }}</li>
        @endforeach
    </ul>
@endif

<div>
    Email
    <input type="email" name="email" value="{{ old('email') }}">
</div>

<div>
    Password
    <input type="password" name="password">
</div>

<div>
    Confirm Password
    <input type="password" name="password_confirmation">
</div>

<div>
    <button type="submit">
        Reset Password
    </button>
</div>
```

Trait used by password controller.

```
/**
 * Get the name of the guest middleware.
 *
 * @return string
 */
protected function guestMiddleware()
{
    $guard = $this->getGuard();

    return $guard ? 'guest:'.$guard : 'guest';
}

/**
 * Display the form to request a password reset link.
 *
 * @return \Illuminate\Http\Response
 */
public function getEmail()
{
    return $this->showLinkRequestForm();
}

/**
 * Display the form to request a password reset link.
 *
 * @return \Illuminate\Http\Response
 */
public function showLinkRequestForm()
{
    if (property_exists($this, 'linkRequestView')) {
        return view($this->linkRequestView);
    }

    if (view()->exists('auth.passwords.email')) {
        return view('auth.passwords.email');
    }

    return view('auth.password');
}

/**
 * Send a reset link to the given user.
 *
 * @param  \Illuminate\Http\Request  $request
 * @return \Illuminate\Http\Response
 */
public function postEmail(Request $request)
{
    return $this->sendResetLinkEmail($request);
}

/**
 * Send a reset link to the given user.
 *
 * @param  \Illuminate\Http\Request  $request
 * @return \Illuminate\Http\Response
 */
public function sendResetLinkEmail(Request $request)
{
    $this->validateSendResetLinkEmail($request);

    $broker = $this->getBroker();

    $response = Password::broker($broker)->sendResetLink(
        $this->getSendResetLinkEmailCredentials($request),
        $this->resetEmailBuilder()
    );

    switch ($response) {
        case Password::RESET_LINK_SENT:
            return $this->getSendResetLinkEmailSuccessResponse($response);
        case Password::INVALID_USER:
        default:
            return $this->getSendResetLinkEmailFailureResponse($response);
    }
}

/**
 * Validate the request of sending reset link.
 *
 * @param  \Illuminate\Http\Request  $request
 * @return void
 */
protected function validateSendResetLinkEmail(Request $request)
{
    $this->validate($request, ['email' => 'required|email']);
}

/**
 * Get the needed credentials for sending the reset link.
 *
 * @param  \Illuminate\Http\Request  $request
 * @return array
 */
protected function getSendResetLinkEmailCredentials(Request $request)
{
    return $request->only('email');
}

/**
 * Get the Closure which is used to build the password reset email message.
 *
 * @return \Closure
 */
protected function resetEmailBuilder()
{
    return function (Message $message) {
        $message->subject($this->getEmailSubject());
    };
}

/**
 * Get the e-mail subject line to be used for the reset link email.
 *
 * @return string
 */
protected function getEmailSubject()
{
    return property_exists($this, 'subject') ? $this->subject : 'Your Password Reset Link';
}

/**
 * Get the response for after the reset link has been successfully sent.
 *
 * @param  string  $response
 * @return \Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\Response
 */
protected function getSendResetLinkEmailSuccessResponse($response)
{
    return redirect()->back()->with('status', trans($response));
}

/**
 * Get the response for after the reset link could not be sent.
 *
 * @param  string  $response
 * @return \Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\Response
 */
protected function getSendResetLinkEmailFailureResponse($response)
{
    return redirect()->back()->withErrors(['email' => trans($response)]);
}

/**
 * Display the password reset view for the given token.
 *
 * If no token is present, display the link request form.
 *
 * @param  \Illuminate\Http\Request  $request
 * @param  string|null  $token
 * @return \Illuminate\Http\Response
 */
public function getReset(Request $request, $token = null)
{
    return $this->showResetForm($request, $token);
}

/**
 * Display the password reset view for the given token.
 *
 * If no token is present, display the link request form.
 *
 * @param  \Illuminate\Http\Request  $request
 * @param  string|null  $token
 * @return \Illuminate\Http\Response
 */
public function showResetForm(Request $request, $token = null)
{
    if (is_null($token)) {
        return $this->getEmail();
    }

    $email = $request->input('email');

    if (property_exists($this, 'resetView')) {
        return view($this->resetView)->with(compact('token', 'email'));
    }

    if (view()->exists('auth.passwords.reset')) {
        return view('auth.passwords.reset')->with(compact('token', 'email'));
    }

    return view('auth.reset')->with(compact('token', 'email'));
}

/**
 * Reset the given user's password.
 *
 * @param  \Illuminate\Http\Request  $request
 * @return \Illuminate\Http\Response
 */
public function postReset(Request $request)
{
    return $this->reset($request);
}

/**
 * Reset the given user's password.
 *
 * @param  \Illuminate\Http\Request  $request
 * @return \Illuminate\Http\Response
 */
public function reset(Request $request)
{
    $this->validate(
        $request,
        $this->getResetValidationRules(),
        $this->getResetValidationMessages(),
        $this->getResetValidationCustomAttributes()
    );

    $credentials = $this->getResetCredentials($request);

    $broker = $this->getBroker();

    $response = Password::broker($broker)->reset($credentials, function ($user, $password) {
        $this->resetPassword($user, $password);
    });

    switch ($response) {
        case Password::PASSWORD_RESET:
            return $this->getResetSuccessResponse($response);
        default:
            return $this->getResetFailureResponse($request, $response);
    }
}

/**
 * Get the password reset validation rules.
 *
 * @return array
 */
protected function getResetValidationRules()
{
    return [
        'token' => 'required',
        'email' => 'required|email',
        'password' => 'required|confirmed|min:6',
    ];
}

/**
 * Get the password reset validation messages.
 *
 * @return array
 */
protected function getResetValidationMessages()
{
    return [];
}

/**
 * Get the password reset validation custom attributes.
 *
 * @return array
 */
protected function getResetValidationCustomAttributes()
{
    return [];
}

/**
 * Get the password reset credentials from the request.
 *
 * @param  \Illuminate\Http\Request  $request
 * @return array
 */
protected function getResetCredentials(Request $request)
{
    return $request->only(
        'email', 'password', 'password_confirmation', 'token'
    );
}

/**
 * Reset the given user's password.
 *
 * @param  \Illuminate\Contracts\Auth\CanResetPassword  $user
 * @param  string  $password
 * @return void
 */
protected function resetPassword($user, $password)
{
    $user->forceFill([
        'password' => bcrypt($password),
        'remember_token' => Str::random(60),
    ])->save();

    Auth::guard($this->getGuard())->login($user);
}

/**
 * Get the response for after a successful password reset.
 *
 * @param  string  $response
 * @return \Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\Response
 */
protected function getResetSuccessResponse($response)
{
    return redirect($this->redirectPath())->with('status', trans($response));
}

/**
 * Get the response for after a failing password reset.
 *
 * @param  Request  $request
 * @param  string  $response
 * @return \Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\Response
 */
protected function getResetFailureResponse(Request $request, $response)
{
    return redirect()->back()
        ->withInput($request->only('email'))
        ->withErrors(['email' => trans($response)]);
}

/**
 * Get the broker to be used during password reset.
 *
 * @return string|null
 */
public function getBroker()
{
    return property_exists($this, 'broker') ? $this->broker : null;
}

/**
 * Get the guard to be used during password reset.
 *
 * @return string|null
 */
protected function getGuard()
{
    return property_exists($this, 'guard') ? $this->guard : null;
}
```

Comment: Have you tried registering? You shouldn't be able to register either since the `create` method in AuthController also bcrypts the password.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's not working because the password is being hashed twice in `resetPassword()`.

To fix it, override the function in `PasswordController.php`

```
protected function resetPassword($user, $password)
{
    $user->forceFill([
        'password' => $password, //Removed bcrypt
        'remember_token' => Str::random(60),
    ])->save();

    Auth::guard($this->getGuard())->login($user);
}
```

Answer (score -1):

You hashed the password twice so that's why it's not working. Your `PasswordController` written should be like this

```
    /**
 * Get the name of the guest middleware.
 *
 * @return string
 */
protected function guestMiddleware()
{
    $guard = $this->getGuard();

    return $guard ? 'guest:'.$guard : 'guest';
}

/**
 * Display the form to request a password reset link.
 *
 * @return \Illuminate\Http\Response
 */
public function getEmail()
{
    return $this->showLinkRequestForm();
}

/**
 * Display the form to request a password reset link.
 *
 * @return \Illuminate\Http\Response
 */
public function showLinkRequestForm()
{
    if (property_exists($this, 'linkRequestView')) {
        return view($this->linkRequestView);
    }

    if (view()->exists('auth.passwords.email')) {
        return view('auth.passwords.email');
    }

    return view('auth.password');
}

/**
 * Send a reset link to the given user.
 *
 * @param  \Illuminate\Http\Request  $request
 * @return \Illuminate\Http\Response
 */
public function postEmail(Request $request)
{
    return $this->sendResetLinkEmail($request);
}

/**
 * Send a reset link to the given user.
 *
 * @param  \Illuminate\Http\Request  $request
 * @return \Illuminate\Http\Response
 */
public function sendResetLinkEmail(Request $request)
{
    $this->validateSendResetLinkEmail($request);

    $broker = $this->getBroker();

    $response = Password::broker($broker)->sendResetLink(
        $this->getSendResetLinkEmailCredentials($request),
        $this->resetEmailBuilder()
    );

    switch ($response) {
        case Password::RESET_LINK_SENT:
            return $this->getSendResetLinkEmailSuccessResponse($response);
        case Password::INVALID_USER:
        default:
            return $this->getSendResetLinkEmailFailureResponse($response);
    }
}

/**
 * Validate the request of sending reset link.
 *
 * @param  \Illuminate\Http\Request  $request
 * @return void
 */
protected function validateSendResetLinkEmail(Request $request)
{
    $this->validate($request, ['email' => 'required|email']);
}

/**
 * Get the needed credentials for sending the reset link.
 *
 * @param  \Illuminate\Http\Request  $request
 * @return array
 */
protected function getSendResetLinkEmailCredentials(Request $request)
{
    return $request->only('email');
}

/**
 * Get the Closure which is used to build the password reset email message.
 *
 * @return \Closure
 */
protected function resetEmailBuilder()
{
    return function (Message $message) {
        $message->subject($this->getEmailSubject());
    };
}

/**
 * Get the e-mail subject line to be used for the reset link email.
 *
 * @return string
 */
protected function getEmailSubject()
{
    return property_exists($this, 'subject') ? $this->subject : 'Your Password Reset Link';
}

/**
 * Get the response for after the reset link has been successfully sent.
 *
 * @param  string  $response
 * @return \Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\Response
 */
protected function getSendResetLinkEmailSuccessResponse($response)
{
    return redirect()->back()->with('status', trans($response));
}

/**
 * Get the response for after the reset link could not be sent.
 *
 * @param  string  $response
 * @return \Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\Response
 */
protected function getSendResetLinkEmailFailureResponse($response)
{
    return redirect()->back()->withErrors(['email' => trans($response)]);
}

/**
 * Display the password reset view for the given token.
 *
 * If no token is present, display the link request form.
 *
 * @param  \Illuminate\Http\Request  $request
 * @param  string|null  $token
 * @return \Illuminate\Http\Response
 */
public function getReset(Request $request, $token = null)
{
    return $this->showResetForm($request, $token);
}

/**
 * Display the password reset view for the given token.
 *
 * If no token is present, display the link request form.
 *
 * @param  \Illuminate\Http\Request  $request
 * @param  string|null  $token
 * @return \Illuminate\Http\Response
 */
public function showResetForm(Request $request, $token = null)
{
    if (is_null($token)) {
        return $this->getEmail();
    }

    $email = $request->input('email');

    if (property_exists($this, 'resetView')) {
        return view($this->resetView)->with(compact('token', 'email'));
    }

    if (view()->exists('auth.passwords.reset')) {
        return view('auth.passwords.reset')->with(compact('token', 'email'));
    }

    return view('auth.reset')->with(compact('token', 'email'));
}

/**
 * Reset the given user's password.
 *
 * @param  \Illuminate\Http\Request  $request
 * @return \Illuminate\Http\Response
 */
public function postReset(Request $request)
{
    return $this->reset($request);
}

/**
 * Reset the given user's password.
 *
 * @param  \Illuminate\Http\Request  $request
 * @return \Illuminate\Http\Response
 */
public function reset(Request $request)
{
    $this->validate(
        $request,
        $this->getResetValidationRules(),
        $this->getResetValidationMessages(),
        $this->getResetValidationCustomAttributes()
    );

    $credentials = $this->getResetCredentials($request);

    $broker = $this->getBroker();

    $response = Password::broker($broker)->reset($credentials, function ($user, $password) {
        $this->resetPassword($user, $password);
    });

    switch ($response) {
        case Password::PASSWORD_RESET:
            return $this->getResetSuccessResponse($response);
        default:
            return $this->getResetFailureResponse($request, $response);
    }
}

/**
 * Get the password reset validation rules.
 *
 * @return array
 */
protected function getResetValidationRules()
{
    return [
        'token' => 'required',
        'email' => 'required|email',
        'password' => 'required|confirmed|min:6',
    ];
}

/**
 * Get the password reset validation messages.
 *
 * @return array
 */
protected function getResetValidationMessages()
{
    return [];
}

/**
 * Get the password reset validation custom attributes.
 *
 * @return array
 */
protected function getResetValidationCustomAttributes()
{
    return [];
}

/**
 * Get the password reset credentials from the request.
 *
 * @param  \Illuminate\Http\Request  $request
 * @return array
 */
protected function getResetCredentials(Request $request)
{
    return $request->only(
        'email', 'password', 'password_confirmation', 'token'
    );
}

/**
 * Reset the given user's password.
 *
 * @param  \Illuminate\Contracts\Auth\CanResetPassword  $user
 * @param  string  $password
 * @return void
 */
protected function resetPassword($user, $password)
{
    $user->forceFill([
        'password' => $password,
        'remember_token' => Str::random(60),
    ])->save();

    Auth::guard($this->getGuard())->login($user);
}

/**
 * Get the response for after a successful password reset.
 *
 * @param  string  $response
 * @return \Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\Response
 */
protected function getResetSuccessResponse($response)
{
    return redirect($this->redirectPath())->with('status', trans($response));
}

/**
 * Get the response for after a failing password reset.
 *
 * @param  Request  $request
 * @param  string  $response
 * @return \Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\Response
 */
protected function getResetFailureResponse(Request $request, $response)
{
    return redirect()->back()
        ->withInput($request->only('email'))
        ->withErrors(['email' => trans($response)]);
}

/**
 * Get the broker to be used during password reset.
 *
 * @return string|null
 */
public function getBroker()
{
    return property_exists($this, 'broker') ? $this->broker : null;
}

/**
 * Get the guard to be used during password reset.
 *
 * @return string|null
 */
protected function getGuard()
{
    return property_exists($this, 'guard') ? $this->guard : null;
}
```

This might be solve your problem.

Comment: PasswordController doesn't need all that code. Only `resetPassword` is being overriden.

Comment: I just rewrite the 'PasswordController' So that The user can copy my code and run into his machine.